# Is it $y'(t)=\cos(t+y)$ separable or no an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know that for the identity $\cos(a+b)= \cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(b)\sin(a)$

but I don't know how to go from here.

Comment: Try the substitution $u=y+t$. This is the general trick for solving DEs of the form $$\frac{dy}{dt}=f(t+y)$$

Answer (score 1):

No, the expression is not separable in this present form. But, you can rewrite it in a separable from.

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = cos(t+y)$$

Suppose you let $u = t+y$ and notice that $\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}(t+y)=1+\frac{dy}{dt}$

In which case it would follow that

$$\frac{du}{dt} = cos(u)+1$$

Now the expression is completely separable.

$$\int \frac{du}{cos(u)+1} =\int dt $$